# error: value toList is not a member of (Object, Object) - Spark Shell

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

```
  val cooccurrences = orders.map(order =>
  (
    order._1,
    order._2.productIterator.toList.combinations(2).map(order_pair =>
        (
            if (order_pair(0)._2 < order_pair(1)._2)
                (order_pair(0)._2, order_pair(1)._2)
            else
                (order_pair(1)._2, order_pair(0)._2),
            order_pair(0)._1 * order_pair(1)._1
        )
    )
  )
)
```

When I submit the last method I'm getting the following error:

```
 <console>:46: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
                   if (order_pair(0)._2 < order_pair(1)._2)
                                     ^
<console>:47: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
                       (order_pair(0)._2, order_pair(1)._2)
                                      ^
<console>:47: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
                       (order_pair(0)._2, order_pair(1)._2)
                                                        ^
<console>:49: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
                       (order_pair(1)._2, order_pair(0)._2),
                                      ^
<console>:49: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
                       (order_pair(1)._2, order_pair(0)._2),
                                                        ^
<console>:50: error: value _1 is not a member of Any
                   order_pair(0)._1 * order_pair(1)._1
                                 ^
```

Anyone knows why I'm getting this errors? Do I need to declare order before the method?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to apply `toList` to an `Object` in the `order._2.toList` call. `order` is of type `(Object, Object)`, hence `order._2` is of type `Object` which does not have a `toList` method.
I assume you had in mind to apply it to the sequence of `(Order, Order)` objects.

Generally, I would advise to explicitly annotate type annotations for more or less complex types.

Answer (score 0):

The value `order._2` is a tuple, and the `toList` method does not apply to tuples directly. You could use `order._2.productIterator.toList` to get a list

Comment: Thanks for your help Samar :) I'm trying to use the new sentence to get the list but it still gives me error. I've updated the code and error above

Comment: From the orders mapping `(x.get("cat"), x.get("quantity"))` It seems that your order._2 will always be a 2 element tuple. Is that right? If so, then I don't see the point of the `combinations(2)` step. Also, the order_pair in the map function expects a two element list of tuples. I am not sure how its expecting that from the previous code.

Comment: with combination(2) I am trying to know how many products combinations I've in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
val orders = transactions.map { x => (
    x.get("id"),
    (x.get("cat"), x.get("quantity")))
}
```

You map transactions which yields in `orders` that is an `RDD` where each element has form of `(valueOfId, valueOfCat, valueofQuantity)`. When you call `order._2.toList` you invoke it on an object `valueOfCat`that does not have such method (it's not a collection).

Comment: Hi sebszyller,

It still gives me an error :( 

<console>:44: error: value toList is not a member of (Object, Object)
           order._2.toList.combinations(2).map(order_pair =>
                    ^

Comment: This is not a copy paste code that will solve your problem; it's an explanation what the problem is. Read the whole post.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at Scala programming... I'm try to know which products combination I have (If product A is "connected" to B). If I understand when I create the cooccurrences I need to invoke order.2_toList to call 3 objects (id,cat,quantity), right? I don't know how to do it :(